# creating "sticky notes" in asp.net c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a message alert using `sticky notes` in c# asp.net web application. how i will do that in web application, please do some help

Comment: Take a look at jQueryUI

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/create-a-sticky-note-effect-in-5-easy-steps-with-css3-and-html5/ check this... this might help u..

Comment: @KamleshArya- Buddy that was already in answer.... Dont u see that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , Firstly , you need to know how to create a custom message box in asp.net .
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25640/ASP-NET-Csharp-MessageBox) is a CodeProject  reference , how to create a custom message box .

And then you should change your custom message box style into sticky note using CSS .
You can find how to create stick note using CSS in
[Link1](http://konigi.com/tools/css-sticky-notes) , 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18118773/1427849) , and
[Link3](http://www.calebthorne.com/code/2013/Oct/css3-sticky-notes) .