# Sticky notes using html

Tags: css, html, web

I am working on a college website and I want to include a Sticky Notes that is shown in windows7.
Any Data or content can be added dynamically and user can add or delete their own sticky notes.

Any Help

Comment: Try searching for `"localStorage"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating sticky-notes ( post-it )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118722/creating-sticky-notes-post-it)

Comment: Help page on html5 `local` & `sessionStorage` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: @Wilf http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage for more information on `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

Comment: @toothbrush - I know it is by W3c, but their site nearly always a=has good examples.

Answer (score 1):

using Html5 and css3 you can make a sticky note. 
Check the link.

```
http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/771_sticky/step5.html
```